# Why does my ReactJS component re-renders even if it's exported with React.memo?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context, memoization, rerender

I have a ReactJS application. The `<App />` component is wrapped with a `<ContextProvider />` component, because I need to have its state shared among components that only have `<App />` as a common ancestor, since it is the `<App />` component that mounts the 3 `React Router v5 <Switch />` that are responsible of rendering:

- the Header
- the Body
- the Right column

To wrap up:

```js
<ContextProvider value={myValue}>
   <App {...props} />
</ContextProvider>
```

Everything is working nice and smoothly, but I have a doubt. The `<Header />` component of a section that consumes the `<ContextProvider />` above is defined and exported in this way:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
// Other imports

function Header() {
  const history = useHistory();

  const goToHomePage = () => { history.push(PATHS.HOME_PAGE); };

  // Some business logic

  console.debug('render');

  return (
    <HeaderComponent
      title={(
        <TitleComponent title="My header" />
      )}
    />
  );
}

export default React.memo(Header);
```

If I inspect the console I can see that every time the values within `<ContextProvider />` change, the `render` string is printed out, meaning that the `<Header />` component is re-rendering.
But this component has no props and is exported via `React.memo`, so I don't understand why it is continuously re-rendering.